# Collision detection between ball & bricks in brick breaker game

Tags: language-agnostic, collision-detection

How do you detect a collision between ball & bricks in a brick breaker game?

Answer (score 2):

### [Bounding Box Collision](http://www.gamedev.net/reference/articles/article735.asp)

That should get you started, and give you some terms to search for. Essentially you treat each brick as a bounding box. Based on the ball position you should be able to determine if the ball collides, this is based on the fact you treat the ball as a simple bounding box, with a set height and width.

Comment: I like the link you provided Finglas.

Comment: @mjboggess Gamedev.net is an excellent site for game development articles in general - some are out of date, but there are some gems there.